# Z-index of my brfore and after pseudo elements not making any effect

Tags: css

i basically am trying to place the after and before pseudo elements behind anchor tag but they are still appearing on upfront , even though i have allocated them z-index

```css
a{
    padding:1rem 1.5rem;
    background-color:whitesmoke;
    border-radius:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:1.1rem;
    color:black;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    user-select:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
a:hover::after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    height:50%;
    width:50%;
    bottom:2px;
    right:3px;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 40px 10px rgb(142, 224, 231);
    transition:all 0.5s;
    animation:shinny2 1s ease-in 1;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    z-index: 0;
}
a:hover::before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    z-index:0;
    height:50%;
    width:50%;
    top:2px;
    left:3px;
    box-shadow:-5px -5px 40px 10px rgb(142, 224, 231);
    animation:shinny1 1s ease-in 1;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Foo</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `<a>` tag has the `z-index` of `2`, which is higher than the default value `auto` (which is `0` if it has a stacking context).

When you assign its child pseudo elements to `z-index: 0;`, even they're smaller than `2`, but they're not going to compare the `z-index` with its parent. (Otherwise you have to assign every of its ascendence with the same or higher `z-index` in order to show them)

Unless you give them a negative `z-index`, then they'll be shown behind the parent, because they're compared with the global stacking context instead of local.

```css
a{
    padding:1rem 1.5rem;
    background-color:whitesmoke;
    border-radius:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:1.1rem;
    color:black;
    position:relative;
    user-select:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
a:hover::after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    height:50%;
    width:50%;
    bottom:2px;
    right:3px;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 40px 10px rgb(142, 224, 231);
    transition:all 0.5s;
    animation:shinny2 1s ease-in 1;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    z-index: -1;
}
a:hover::before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    height:50%;
    width:50%;
    top:2px;
    left:3px;
    box-shadow:-5px -5px 40px 10px rgb(142, 224, 231);
    animation:shinny1 1s ease-in 1;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Foo</a>
```

But using a negative `z-index` has a drawback, that it will be appeared behind every other elements but not only its parent, unless they have a even lower `z-index` (negative z-index hell).

```css
main {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
}

a{
    padding:1rem 1.5rem;
    background-color:whitesmoke;
    border-radius:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:1.1rem;
    color:black;
    position:relative;
    user-select:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
a:hover::after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    height:50%;
    width:50%;
    bottom:2px;
    right:3px;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 40px 10px rgb(142, 224, 231);
    transition:all 0.5s;
    animation:shinny2 1s ease-in 1;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    z-index: -1;
}
a:hover::before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    height:50%;
    width:50%;
    top:2px;
    left:3px;
    box-shadow:-5px -5px 40px 10px rgb(142, 224, 231);
    animation:shinny1 1s ease-in 1;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <a href="#">Foo</a>  
</main>
```

If don't want to mess around with `z-index`, a workaround is to utilize `translateZ` to put the pseudo elements behind its content, that will only be affected in the local 3d stacking context. So you don't need to worry about the interations with other elements.

```css
a {
  /* make sure the 3d stack works */
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: inline-block;
}

a::before, a::after {
  /* put the pseudo elements behind the content */
  transform: translateZ(-1px);
}
```

```css
main {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
}

a{
    padding:1rem 1.5rem;
    background-color:whitesmoke;
    border-radius:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:1.1rem;
    color:black;
    position:relative;
    user-select:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
a:hover::after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    height:50%;
    width:50%;
    bottom:2px;
    right:3px;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 40px 10px rgb(142, 224, 231);
    transition:all 0.5s;
    animation:shinny2 1s ease-in 1;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    transform: translateZ(-1px);
}
a:hover::before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    height:50%;
    width:50%;
    top:2px;
    left:3px;
    box-shadow:-5px -5px 40px 10px rgb(142, 224, 231);
    animation:shinny1 1s ease-in 1;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    transform: translateZ(-1px);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <a href="#">Foo</a>
</main>
```

Comment: that might be  great idea but why isnt my code working out? i Am trying to figure out the reason also or else i will keeep on runing into it

Comment: I don't think the "text" layer of your anchor actually has a z-index. You'd prolly want to wrap it with another element, e.g. span

Comment: text layer comes in the a tag ,so why will that z index not work on it

Comment: @lakshya I've added more information about this solution and why your approach didn't work.

Comment: @lakshya _"text layer comes in the a tag ,so why will that z index not work on it"_ - the text does not create a layer of its own, the `a` element _is_ the "layer" of the text. Text and the background color are _one_ layer here.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring `z-index: -1` on the pseudo-elements does the job.

It appears that the z-index of the pseudo-elements is relative to the anchor. Giving the anchor `z-index: 0` keeps the stacking order of the elements while allowing the pseudo-elements to be underneath only the anchor.

```css
div {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

p {
  padding: 1.5em;
  background-color: ghostwhite;
}

a {
  position:relative;
  padding:1rem 1.5rem;
  font-size:1.1rem;
  text-decoration:none;
  background-color:whitesmoke;
  border-radius:12px;
  z-index: 0;
}

a:hover::after,
a:hover::before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  height:50%;
  width:50%;
  z-index: -1;
}


a:hover::after {
  bottom:2px;
  right:3px;
  box-shadow:5px 5px 40px 10px rgb(142, 224, 231);
}

a:hover::before {
  top:2px;
  left:3px;
  box-shadow:-5px -5px 40px 10px rgb(142, 224, 231);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p><a href="#">Foo</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: it isnt working since i have applied a background to parent container of a tag

Comment: i am using display gird in the container. does that affect it?

Comment: @lakshya It appears that the z-index of the pseudo-elements is relative to the anchor. Giving the anchor `z-index: 0` keeps the stacking order of the elements while allowing the pseudo-elements to be underneath only the anchor. CSS Grid on the parent does not affect this.